# python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1, while using a makefile

Tags: python, makefile, package, setup.py, homekit

i was generating the Apple Homekit ADK(https://github.com/apple/HomeKitADK) documentation following their guide (https://github.com/apple/HomeKitADK?tab=readme-ov-file#documentation), when this error occurred:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-meixdz0s/lxml/

Any guesses on How I can solve that?

i tried searching online and installing/upgrading setuptools and ez_setup, but i get the same result